# Joining a node to a cluster

Tags: cassandra

I have tried to do necessary configuration to deploy multiple instances of Cassandra on 2 different nodes of multi-node cluster.  But the nodes are having trouble seeing each other.  Can someone give me an advice how to join a node to my cluster?

Comment: We will not be able to help you without any information. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

To join a node to a cluster, the following need to match-up in the nodes' cassandra.yaml files:

- `cluster_name`
- `endpoint_snitch`
- `num_tokens`

Get your first node running, and make sure the following ports are open on your firewall or internal network:

- 7000 (gossip)
- 7001 (if using node-to-node SSL)
- 7199 (JMX)
- 9042 (client connections)

On your second node, make sure the second node has the first node's IP address in its seed list.  All of your nodes should share the same seed list, as well.  Depending on the size of your cluster, you should have two or three per data center.

Example:

```
      # seeds is actually a comma-delimited list of addresses.
      - seeds: "192.168.0.100,192.168.0.101"
```

Once your seed nodes are set, fire-up your second node and it should join.  If it doesn't check the system.log for errors.